# IIS7 redirect between virtual dirs

Tags: asp.net, session, iis-7, virtual-directory

in our asp.net app, we have several virtual directories. In IIS7, these are called "applications" and they all have the same application pool, running in classic pipeline mode.

- www.webapp.com/example1
- www.webapp.com/example2
- etc.

They all point to the same physical directory, say C:\webapp. The only difference is  they each have an underlying virtual dir that points to a different CSS folder, which is located in C:\webapp\styles\ (eg. C:\webapp\styles\example1\base.css, etc)

We use forms authentication and the built-in membership provider. The problem we have is this:

When a user is browsing www.webapp.com/example1/page.aspx and clicks on a link that redirects to www.webapp.com/example2/otherpage.aspx,the user is instead redirected to www.webapp.com/example2/login.aspx. It seems as if the session expired.

We don't really know where to look for a solution, any pointers are greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!
Stijn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found the solution so I thought I'd share this with the SO community:

set AppDomainAppId to a fixed value (in this case applicationName) through reflection:

Globals.asax.cs:

```
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // make sure all set the same AppDomainAppId
        FieldInfo runtimeInfo = typeof(HttpRuntime).GetField("_theRuntime", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        if (runtimeInfo == null) return;
        HttpRuntime theRuntime = (HttpRuntime)runtimeInfo.GetValue(null);
        if (theRuntime == null) return;
        FieldInfo appNameInfo = typeof(HttpRuntime).GetField("_appDomainAppId", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        if (appNameInfo == null) return;
        var appName = (String)appNameInfo.GetValue(theRuntime);
        if (appName != "applicationName") appNameInfo.SetValue(theRuntime, "applicationName");
    }
```